# ReactJS: get mediumtext from MySQL and view formatted text

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I have a very specific problem, so:
I have a medium text in My MySQL database. for example (with breakline):

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

I would like to get this text now using the get HTTP method and on my site display, all `Lorem Ipsum` in **bold**.

Is something possible to get?
I use ReactJS with Redux + Redux-Saga

or Maybe **IN databases**, I can insert the medium text **in html** but how to display it on the frontend then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store html and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render it. You can have a deeper look into it reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337289/react-js-set-innerhtml-vs-dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

```js
const text = '<strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit';

const App = ({html}) => (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
)

ReactDOM.render(<App html={text} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```