# Adding markup on string without dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs

I have a `modal` component that receives two strings from a `home` component, it's easy to take those strings and render them on one single string with the correct markup on the `modal.tsx` with this

```
return <>No markup: {firstString},  with markup: <strong>{secondString}<strong><>
```

But what I actually want to do is render the whole string first in the other component to keep the `modal` component agnostic and just render whatever string and its markup.

The problem is that on the `home` component if I store the string  with markup on state, I then have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on the modal.

Home.tsx

```
const message = `No markup: {firstString},  with markup: <strong>{secondString}<strong>`
```

Modal.tsx

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message }}>{}</div>
```

Is there another way to do this, and if not is this actually dangerous?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339542/5953610

Answer (score 1):

In terms of directly inlined HTML it is a potential XSS vulnerability.
That's why React, as well as other frameworks, try to make such places explicit and conspicuous.

But in your particular case, you control "inlined HTML" by React:

```
const message = `No markup: {firstString},  with markup: <strong>{secondString}<strong>`
```

XSS vulnerability is more about user input.

You have one more option to make "inlined HTML" as safe as possible (including user input) - use Markdown for example)

Gatsby - is a good example of Markdown usage in the React world
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/adding-markdown-pages/

Comment: Thanks, I have played around with Gatsby and it's very interesting, however not an option on this project. In this example there are no inputs it is just a modal box informing with a simple strong tag.