# How can I use HTML tags from API and display on page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

[image]

```html
<p>This is one of the most accurate answers that is able to resolve the birthday of 29th of Feb compared to any year of 28th Feb.
</p>\n\n
<pre class=\ "lang-cs prettyprint-override\">
  <code>public int GetAge(DateTime birthDate)\n
```

I want to develop on my display page of answers and using this tags from API for building page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js: Set innerHTML vs dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337289/react-js-set-innerhtml-vs-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: First of all i need to say you need to improve your question with code, for example how you paste the code from API? With this information i think you need to use `innerHTML`

Comment: but I use React.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [ReactJS  dangerously set inner html](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
const htmlString = '<h1>Hello World! </h1>';
const App = () => (
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />
);
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

good luck.