# Parse html tags from a JSON file in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

In a ReactJs application, fetching data from a Json file which contains some HTML tags, which is displayed as string without interpreting it as HTML.

I considered to use dangerouslySetInnterHTML. However, according to React's official documentation, setting HTML from code seems to be risky.

Any other best practice to achieve the same.

Sample Json:

```
{
  "FAQ" : {
             "contents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <a href=\"www.test.com\">www.test.com</a>",
          }
}
```

Comment: [Do it answer on your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339542/14135825)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse html tags in a Json content in a React application there is a npm package available name ['html-to-react'](https://github.com/hedgedoc/html-to-react)

Usage:

```
import React from 'react';
import convertHtmlToReact from '@hedgedoc/html-to-react';

class HtmlComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const html = '<div>Example HTML string</div>';
    return <div>{ convertHtmlToReact (html, true) }</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).